# Quartz Cron job required that executes at 12 am every 2 weeks

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

http://www.cronmaker.com/

I am using the above link and trying to create a cron job which runs at 12AM on the server every 2 weeks. Could anyone help.

Regards
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

After a google search I found this, maybe it can help you:

```
 https://coderwall.com/p/yzzu5a
```

Comment: I cannot use expr inside the cron formulae. I can just modify the allowed parameters out of 0 0 0 0 0 0 to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've tagged your question with `quartz-scheduler`, I assume that you are using Quartz.

You can use the `CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder` to set an interval of days, weeks, months, etc.

```
ScheduleBuilder schb = CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.calendarIntervalSchedule().withIntervalInWeeks(2);
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startAt(DateBuilder.todayAt(0, 0, 0)).withSchedule(schb).forJob(muJob).build();
```

Here we are telling quartz to run our job every 2 weeks, starting today at 00:00:00 (12 :00 AM ?)

If you insist on using `cron` style jobs , this might be helpful : http://www.fclose.com/1199/how-to-run-a-cron-job-every-two-weeks-months-days/